# Search string to see if it contains values in an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, search, indexof

I am trying to see if a string contains keywords to determine if it is a town or road.  Because of the number of different values, rather than writing:

```
(Road.search("Way") != -1) || (Road.search("Road") != -1) || (Road.search("Ave") != -1)
```

for each value, I wonder if there is an easier way?

Values are

Cl,
Close,
Rd,
Road,
Dr,
Drive,
Sq,
Square,
Way,
Ave,
Avenue,
Gardens,
Loke,
Ct,
Court,
Terrace

Answer (score 5):

Quick and easy with some regex:

```
if (/\b(road|rd|ave|avenue|cl|close)\b/i.test(string)) {
    // It's a road
}
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how may ors that you have?